# py-datatable Replace empty string in column with NaN

Tags: python, datatable, py-datatable

In a python data table, I wanted to replace empty strings with NaN. When I tried, I get the below error. It works with pandas. Thanks in advance for the help.

Datatable Syntax I tried:

```
dt[:,"column_name"].replace('',np.nan)
```

Error Received:

> Cannot replace string value `''` with a value of type <class 'float'>

pandas syntax that worked:

```
pd["column_name"]=pd["column_name"].replace('',np.nan)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Py datatable syntax to update (replace) one of the columns based on its value:

```
import datatable as dt
mydt = dt.Frame(a=['a','b','c','','d','e'])
mydt[dt.f.a == '', dt.update(a = None)]
```

Datatable before update:

```
mydt
   | a 
-- + --
 0 | a 
 1 | b 
 2 | c 
 3 |   
 4 | d 
 5 | e
```

Datatable after update:

```
mydt
   | a 
-- + --
 0 | a 
 1 | b 
 2 | c 
 3 | NA
 4 | d 
 5 | e
```

works with version 0.10.0 or later

Bonus answer: to accomplish the opposite - replace missing values with some constant value use function `isna()`:

```
mydt = dt.Frame(a=['a','b','c', None,'d','e'])
mydt[dt.isna(dt.f.a), dt.update(a = 'NULL')]
```